# REST Best Practice GET with context parameters

Tags: rest

We have a series of REST services that pull resources by identifier but we've been recently tasked with passing disclosure parameters to save with audit.

What use to be...

```
GET entity/{id}
```

now turns into something like...

```
GET entity/{id}?requestName=&requestingOrganization=&reasonForUse=&verificationMethod=&otherAuditDisclosureProperties....
```

The state of `entity` does not change and is still idempotent however we must audit the additional information with each call in order to provide it.

First thought was to construct a body instead but that did not seem proper for a GET.  This is the second approach using query parameters which have no intention of querying/filtering.  These additional parameters are truly context information captured at the point of request.  These are the equivalent of SAML attributes within a SOAP call that live outside of the SOAP body (which makes me think as possible header attributes).

Also note, that this information is relayed so the authentication token provided is for the service user calling in and not the actual identity of the context.  The identity of the original caller is implicitly trusted in the trust framework surrounding.

How would you define this verb/path?

Comment: Can those params be inferred by the server or they must be defined by the client? Are those params per request or could they be global to a client (as in client/server architecture) or a customer account?

Comment: Unfortunately the server does not have this additional information and they are per request.  Basically I can request the same resource but for a different reason (which we must capture).

Comment: Is both client and server the same corporation? can you provide more info on the problem you are trying to solve? not the solution...which seems horrible. How do you ensure proper use of reasons to invoke a service? As a client why should I do it? You are putting a lot of burden on my side. I wouldn't use such API or would not inform the reasons as you expect. Too much work. If you provide more info on the problem I could suggest a better approach.

Comment: This is a highly regulated system with clearly defined audit requirements when providing responses to requests that cross domains (yes external users).  They are modeled after SOAP/SAML exchange standards where the body encapsulates the general the request and the signed SAML attributes contain the contextual information.  We're trying to introduce a REST based alternative but need to cover the legal audit requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a custom header: `vnd.mycompany.myheader`; where you put all the params you need in some parseable format: `name1=value1; name2=value2`. You take the waste out of the query string.

**The off-topic response**

I cannot imagine an scenario where you are asking the user of an API for such subjective information, that requires a lot of effort to provide (as it changes per request) and provides no value to the client. It is only for your internal use. The most probable result is clients hard coding those values and repeating them over in all requests.

If the client is internal you may be looking for ways to correlate requests that span multiple services, like [Sleuth](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/), which will let you understand why clients are using your API.

If the client is external, think of making surveys and personal interviews with developers. I'd also suggest that you first nurture your API community to reach those people and understand how and why they use your API.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Daniel Cerecedo. The proper way is to add the information as part of your Request Header.
A general information can be found at: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html
The implementation will depends on your programming language.